# Raspberry Pi wifi adapter constantly down

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless-adapter, raspbian-buster

Both my Raspberry Pi 1 B+ and Zero W 1.1  have the same issue when I attempt to connect TP-Link WN725N adapter - it seems its constantly down, despite changing the state manually:

```
pi@pr-grape:~ $ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether **:**:**:**:**:** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether **:**:**:**:**:** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
pi@pr-grape:~ $ sudo ip link set wlan1 up
pi@pr-grape:~ $ sudo ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether **:**:**:**:**:** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether **:**:**:**:**:** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`dmesg` does not display ANY new information after those commands, `lsusb` recognizes the RTL8188EUS device correctly. This adapter was working properly with previous Debian releases(Wheezy and older), with new installations it seems to not cooperate at all. How can I further investigate this issue?

*(moved from comment, as requested by @Ingo)*

Note: the temporary solution is using

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan1 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wext
```

command, but I have to write it on each boot.

Comment: Please move the very important information from the comment to your question. You can edit your question.

Comment: @Ingo done as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the USB/WiFi adapter TP-Link WN725N is an older model and does work only with old background driver **wext** used by wpa_supplicant. If you use **systemd-netword** you can easy make two services for wpa_supplicant that will manage each interface independent. Here a suggestion I would do it. Switch to systemd-networkd:

```
# disable debian networking and dhcpcd
rpi ~$ sudo -Es
rpi ~# systemctl mask networking.service dhcpcd.service
rpi ~# sudo mv /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces~
rpi ~# sed -i '1i resolvconf=NO' /etc/resolvconf.conf

# enable systemd-networkd
rpi ~# systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service systemd-resolved.service
rpi ~# ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Create this file with your settings for `country=`, `ssid=` and `psk=` for the service to the **wlan0** interface and enable it:

```
rpi ~# cat >/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="TestNet"
    psk="realyNotMyPassword"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
rpi ~# systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

And just do the same for the interface **wlan1**:

```
rpi ~# cat >/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf <<EOF
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="OtherTestNet"
    psk="realyNotMyPassword"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service
```

Now modify the service for **wlan1** so that it only uses background driver **wext**. Edit the service with:

```
rpi ~# sudo systemctl edit wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-%I.conf -Dwext -i%I
```

The empty `ExecStart=` is important. It will disable the current setting so you can set a new one in the next line.

Reboot and check with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
rpi ~$ systemctl status wpa_supplicant@wlan1.service
```